# burninate [unavailable]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[unavailable](/questions/tagged/unavailable) on SO is useless. We should kill it with fire.

Comment: There are only 32 posts... Might just be easier to manually remove them

Comment: Fair enough; quite a few of them probably deserve close votes as well.

Comment: I'm morbidly curious: what was the [unavailable] tag used for?

Comment: Mostly issues with HTTP 503 "Service Unavailable". Although it was slapped on questions about just about anything not being available.

Comment: [(for your future burninations)](http://stackapps.com/questions/4207/burninator-toolkit)

Comment: @Won't: thanks; I should pay more attention to stackapps.